# Android Animation Flicker

Tags: android, android-animation

I've been trawling through as many threads on this topic that I can find on the flicker that arises in Android 2.2 when dealing with AnimationListeners, but I can't quite solve my issue.

What I've got is a LinearLayout 'popover' that the user touches to move down about 100 pixels, and touches again to move it back up. I've finally got it working on the first part without any flicker (thanks to the suggestion to call clearAnimation() on the view being animated), but when doing the opposite (ie, moving the view back up), there's a flicker at the start. I can't really call clearAnimation() in the onAnimationStart() method as it won't animate!

Of course, all animation works perfectly if I used setFillAfter() without any animation listener, but then the view's touch area won't move (because the view itself hasn't "actually" moved).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
this.popoverTab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popoverTab.setClickable(false);
        popoverTab.setFocusable(false);
        if (popoverHidden) {
            Log.d(TAG, "About to show popover");
            // the popover is currently hidden, show it.
            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100, 0);
            animation.setDuration(700);
            animation.setFillBefore(true);
            animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    footer.layout(footer.getLeft(), (footer.getTop() - 100), footer.getRight(), footer.getBottom());
                }
            });
            footer.startAnimation(animation);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "About to hide popover");
            // the popover is showing, hide it.
            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 100);
            animation.setDuration(700);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    footer.clearAnimation();
                    footer.layout(footer.getLeft(), (footer.getTop() + 100), footer.getRight(), footer.getBottom());
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            footer.startAnimation(animation);
        }
        // invert.
        popoverHidden = !popoverHidden;
        popoverTab.setClickable(true);
        popoverTab.setFocusable(true);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had the same problem and after few days I found the solution ... thanx to:

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg67535.html

> I figured out a solution to this problem.  The clue came from the fact
>   that when showing the view, everything worked fine.
>   Apparently, when the animation is running, the update that would be
>   forced by the show happens in the background and doesn't cause the
>   flicker.  Adding a short animation to the back end of the
>   onAnimationEnd() when we are hiding the view makes the flicker go
>   away.
>
> Here is the new onAndimationEnd() in the working code
>
> ```
>   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
>             animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
>             animation.setDuration(1);
>             mPlayer0Panel.startAnimation(animation);
>    }
> ```

Comment: I had the blink problem(i dont know if flicker and blink are the same thing) and this solved the situation.

Comment: After searching for a long time this saved my day.

Comment: It works on my project, which uses Floating Action Button using Rebound(Facebook) and Backboard(Tumblr).

Comment: really strange, works as of today (tried on android 4.2.2, 4.4, 5.0, 5.0.1, 5.1.1, 6.0, 6.0.1)... thx a lot

Answer (score 13):

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
    footer.clearAnimation();
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same error, but it only appeared in some views, although all had the same implementation. As it turned out, it happened for two reasons:

- When I had     `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in my root xml element
- When the problematic view was directly connected to the root xml element

So, two solutions, either remove the `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` tag (suggested since you're not using it), or use a wrapper Layout around the problematic view! So instead of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
    </LinearLayout>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

, do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: One of the underrated answers in this thread. The reason my view flickers after animation is because of ```android:animateLayoutChanges="true"```. I think it overlaps with ```Transition``` coded programatically. Removing ```android:animateLayoutChanges="true"``` has solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to use `clearAnimation()` on `onAnimationEnd()`.

Try this:

1. Use `setFillBefore(true)` and `setFillAfter(true)` on **both** animations
2. Set the correct layout properties when starting and when ending **both** animations

Comment: I still ended up with a flicker when moving the panel back up. I got around the issue by putting a dummy view behind it containing the same content as the one in front of it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it seems that adjusting the view.layout() causes the flicker.

Answer (score 3):

I searched for all stackoverflow posts for animation issue (flicker and sluggish).
I didnt find any perfect answer. But I have found the solution for the same, which is as below,

onStart of Animation use,

```
view_you_want_to_animate.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

onEnd of Animation use,

```
view_you_want_to_animate.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Now my view does not have flicker or sluggish behavior when my view is animating. 
It works well for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well, both with a stand-alone alpha animation and a translate + scale animation set.

Comment: `setDrawingCacheEnabled` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Alrite, I had the same issue that made me search for it, I ended up in this post. Found a solution for my issue, thought to share my solution.

I had many animations running but flickering started recently, but when I traced the issue found the flickering occured after drawing list of animations under a *for* loop. (array List)

I simply added try catch to avoid the issue after locating it, the problem; some of the animations were removed on fly but there were not enough time for a thread to update, so the loop still tried and failed but not shown instead it flickered, but under try and catch on the array list drawing fixed my issue.