# How to use Translate Animation

Tags: java, android

How do I make Relative Layout get smaller from the bottom to top animation and stop at height of 150dp using a Translation Animation? Here is what I got.

```
TranslateAnimation translation = new TranslateAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, relativeLayout.getHeight(), 0.0f);
            translation.setDuration(2000);
            relativeLayout.startAnimation(translation);
```

Comment: are you getting any error. Make your question clearly

Comment: @MakeItSimple No i am not getting any error. Id just like to set the Relative Layout to 150dp with the sliding animation.

Comment: i mean from from bottom to top your layout should animate, right?

Comment: yes, i want layout to animate from bottom to top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understood, you need to translate your layout from bottom to top or top to bottom. Try like this

**Bottom to Top**

```
public void SlideToAbove() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_layout.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_layout.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_layout.getWidth(), rl_layout.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            rl_layout.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}
```

**Top to Bottom**

```
public void SlideToDown() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_layout.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_layout.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_layout.getWidth(), rl_layout.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, rl_layout.getWidth(), 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            rl_layout.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}
```

Refer [this link also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919264/top-to-bottom-translate-animation)