# Swipe to next activity animation style help :: android

Tags: android

Guys i need your help i am new app development and stack overflow. I need to make animation drag a button or something downward and brings a new activity after it.
NOTE: i cant put an image here but i can try to make my requirement clear with chars.

```
  |______V______| --> button or image

         |
         | --> dragging down
         v
```

after dragging down (Button or image) in result a new activity comes from top to bottom.
Any Help Links or suggestion will be appreciated?

Comment: i guess you need this https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: Yeah this is help full but actually my question is little different i want to bring new activity from top to bottom. its about refreshing listView not activity :(

Comment: I am not getting from top to bottom?

Comment: see, there is an image or button on header of current activity when user drag it downward a new activity starts to come after it. you can take it as some one drag the rope of curtain and it start comming down. have i made my point clear?

Comment: ok got it :) let me write some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActivityLogin extends Activity {

    private boolean isUp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(final View v) {

                        final float direction = (isUp) ? -1 : 1;
                        final float yDelta = getScreenHeight()
                                - (2 * v.getHeight());
                        final int layoutTopOrBottomRule = (isUp) ? RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP
                                : RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM;

                        final Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,
                                0, 0, yDelta * direction);

                        animation.setDuration(500);

                        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                            }

                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                            }

                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                                // fix flicking
                                // Source :
                                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387711/android-animation-flicker
                                TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
                                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                                anim.setDuration(2);
                                v.startAnimation(anim);

//                              // set new params
//                              LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(v
//                                      .getLayoutParams());
//                              params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
//                              params.addRule(layoutTopOrBottomRule);
//                              v.setLayoutParams(params);



                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Open New Activity here", 1).show();
                            }
                        });

                        v.startAnimation(animation);

                        // reverse direction
                        isUp = !isUp;
                    }
                });
    }

    private float getScreenHeight() {

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        return (float) displaymetrics.heightPixels;

    }
}
```

and your activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drag Me" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now where i have shown Toast message you need to show your next activity there.