# How to change the color of a view in Android as long as a repeatListener button is pressed without flickering

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-button

I have the following Java code

```
package com.example.game;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.example.game.databinding.FragmentTestBinding;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test extends Fragment {
    /*
    Game variables
     */

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private int numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 = 8000;

    private int currentTimeSlot;

    private float verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine = 0.049f;
    private float percentageHeightOfEventElement = 0.071f;

    int widthDisplay;
    int heightDisplay;

    //Type of View_Game_Events
    public static final String VIEW_EVENT_RECTANGLE_SOLAR = "Solar";

    private FragmentTestBinding binding;

    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    ConstraintSet constraintSet ;

    //Variables for the single view event
    View_Game_Event_Rectangle[] viewEvent;
    boolean [] isViewEventActive;
    Drawable[] drawingsForTheViewEvents;
    private static int nextFreeIndexForViewEvent;
    private static int numberOfViewEventInArray = 10;
    ArrayList<View_Game_Event_Rectangle> arrayList_GameEventRectangles;

    private int [] orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel;

    private boolean fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;

    private CountDownTimer cdt;

    private  final long DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER = 100; //100ms

    private int numberOfTimeSlotsUntilTheEndOfScreen = (int)(numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * 2/(DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER));


    public Test() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        nextFreeIndexForViewEvent = 0;
        viewEvent = new View_Game_Event_Rectangle[numberOfViewEventInArray];
        drawingsForTheViewEvents = new Drawable[numberOfViewEventInArray];
        arrayList_GameEventRectangles = new ArrayList<View_Game_Event_Rectangle>();
        isViewEventActive = new boolean[numberOfViewEventInArray];

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getWindowManager();
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        widthDisplay = size.x;
        heightDisplay = size.y;


        container.getContext();
        constraintLayout= binding.constraintLayout;


        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = true;
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        constraintLayout = binding.constraintLayout;
        constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();

        //Define the repeatListener
        binding.repeatButton.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener) new RepeatListener(30, 30, new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                View_Game_Event_Rectangle activeElement = null;
                for (int currentElement =0; currentElement <arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++) {
                    activeElement = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement);
                }

                if (activeElement!=null) {
                    activeElement.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_solar_2).mutate());
                    // Schedule the change back to R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_solar_1 after 10 milliseconds
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    View_Game_Event_Rectangle finalActiveElement = activeElement;
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Change the background back to R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_solar_1
                            finalActiveElement.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_solar_1).mutate());
                        }
                    }, 300);
                }



            }
        }));


        startGame();
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    public void startGame () {
        startRound();
    }

    public void startRound () {
        orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel = new int[5000];
        orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel [54] = 20;



        //Create the array list with the Game_Event_Rectangles
        for (int i =0; i<orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel.length; i++) {
            if (orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel[i] >0) {
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.add(new View_Game_Event_Rectangle(getActivity(), VIEW_EVENT_RECTANGLE_SOLAR, i+1, orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel[i]));
            }
        }

        countDownTime();

    }

    private void updateScreen() {

        /*
        Iterate through all elements
         */
        for (int currentElement =0; currentElement <arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++) {


            //Create view and set
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 15) {

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setActive(true);


                //Set the parameters and the backgorund of the view element
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));

                if(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getEventType().equals(VIEW_EVENT_RECTANGLE_SOLAR)) {
                    arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_solar_1).mutate());
                }


                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setId(View.generateViewId());

                //Make the view invisible (before it's appearence time)
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                // Set the ConstraintLayout programatically for the view
                constraintLayout.addView(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement));
                constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
                constraintSet.constrainPercentHeight(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), percentageHeightOfEventElement);

                float widthConstrainPercentage_element1 = (float)(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration() / 100.0);
                float duration = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration();


                constraintSet.constrainPercentWidth(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), widthConstrainPercentage_element1);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);

                float horizontalBias = 1.0f ;
                constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), horizontalBias);
                constraintSet.setVerticalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine);
                constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

            }

            //Shift the view to the right border of the display
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 10) {


                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setTranslationX(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getWidth());
            }


            //Animate view element
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot()) {
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                View rectangle = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement);
                int rectangleWidth = rectangle.getWidth();
                float distanceToCover_current = widthDisplay + rectangleWidth;
                float distanceToCover_normalizedObject = widthDisplay + 20;
                double ratioDistanceDifference = distanceToCover_current /distanceToCover_normalizedObject;
                long durationForTheAnimation = (long)(numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * ratioDistanceDifference);

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).animate().setDuration(durationForTheAnimation).translationX(widthDisplay*(-1)).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();

            }
        }

    }

    private void countDownTime(){


        cdt = new CountDownTimer(100000, DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER) {
            boolean delay = true;
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(delay) {
                    delay = false;
                } else {
                    currentTimeSlot++;

                    updateScreen();
                    delay = true;
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                updateScreen();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        // Reset your variable to false
        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;

        // And clean up any postDelayed callbacks that are waiting to fire
        cdt.cancel();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the code for the RepeatListener:

```
package com.example.game;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * A class, that can be used as a TouchListener on any view (e.g. a Button).
 * It cyclically runs a clickListener, emulating keyboard-like behaviour. First
 * click is fired immediately, next one after the initialInterval, and subsequent
 * ones after the normalInterval.
 *
 * <p>Interval is scheduled after the onClick completes, so it has to run fast.
 * If it runs slow, it does not generate skipped onClicks. Can be rewritten to
 * achieve this.
 */
public class RepeatListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private int initialInterval;
    private final int normalInterval;
    private final View.OnClickListener clickListener;
    private View touchedView;

    private Runnable handlerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(touchedView.isEnabled()) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, normalInterval);
                clickListener.onClick(touchedView);
            } else {
                // if the view was disabled by the clickListener, remove the callback
                handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
                touchedView.setPressed(false);
                touchedView = null;
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * @param initialInterval The interval after first click event
     * @param normalInterval The interval after second and subsequent click
     *       events
     * @param clickListener The OnClickListener, that will be called
     *       periodically
     */
    public RepeatListener(int initialInterval, int normalInterval,
                          View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
        if (clickListener == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null runnable");
        if (initialInterval < 0 || normalInterval < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative interval");

        this.initialInterval = initialInterval;
        this.normalInterval = normalInterval;
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
                handler.postDelayed(handlerRunnable, initialInterval);
                touchedView = view;
                touchedView.setPressed(true);
                clickListener.onClick(view);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
                touchedView.setPressed(false);
                touchedView = null;
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

What happens is that a simple custom made view rectangle `View_Game_Event_Rectangle` is animated from the right to the left.Then I have a repeat listener. When the repeat listener is pressed the background color of the custom view is changed from its original one `R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_solar_1` to a new one `R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_solar_2`. A handler then changes the color back after some time. The problem is, that the custom made view rectangle flickers while holding the repeatListener pressed. I tried to change the time delay for the handler but this did not solve the problem (when the delay is too high, the color remains changed for a long time). What I want is that the color of the custom made view rectangle keeps changed as long as the repeatListener button is pressed. After the repeatListener button is not pressed any more, the color should change back to its original one. The improtant aspect is that while the button is pressed, the custom made view rectangle should not flicker but just have the alternative color `R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_solar_2`.

**Please**: Please can someone share his/her idea? I'd be quite thankful.

Comment: try this one https://parallelcodes.com/how-to-create-android-gradient-buttons-different-designs/

Comment: @AniruddhParihar: Thanks for your comment. What exactly shall I try there? I had a look at the link but don't see at all how this should be related to my question

Comment: try this gradient https://parallelcodes.com/how-to-create-android-gradient-buttons-different-designs/#:~:text=res%3Edrawable%3Ebuttonstyle1.xml%3A

Comment: Or try this Gradient for button

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/red"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/yellow"/>
    <item android:color="@color/green"/>
</selector>

Comment: @AniruddhParihar: Thanks for your comment. Actually not the button should change when pressing (that would be easy). When the button is hold pressed the custom made rectangle view should change and this makes the whole thing difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is that the color of the custom made view rectangle keeps changed as long as the repeatListener button is pressed.

Color of you rectangle is changed back after 300ms, thats what you have coded. This might give a flicker.

Its hard to tell from the provided code what is exactly wrong. You have not provided code for `RepeatListener`. I suspect that the code inside:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
```

gets executed even after first time button was touched. You should execute your on touch code when `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and when its `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, handle touch up action. Otherwise you will intercept also `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` events which can give you flicker. I assume this is not implemented in `RepeatListener`.

So, when `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` change color to the one you want to stay for the time user touches button. Then when `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` comes, change the color back. I dont see a need for `postDelayed` here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I indeed forgot to poste the code of the RepeatListener. I now updated the question and you can see the code. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: So you handle ACTION_DOWN/ACTION_UP as I suspected, if you want to keep the color intact for the time of touch down on the button, then you must tract when the color gets changed. I suppose its in those runnables you are calling. Code is quite complicated, I would suggest getting rid of those runnable and just set the color in ACTION_DOWN, and bring that color back in ACTION_UP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to admit that I don't understand at all what I should do. Where and how shall I change the color of the custom view? And what do you mean by ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP? Actually I only have one button, so there is no such thing as up or down in the button. Further, I need to change the color in the main fragment `Test ` as I have multiple different versions of the custom view rectangle and they should change to different background colors. Also, where shall I get rid of the runnable? I think I need them for the repeatListener and to change the color

Comment: You currently change colors in Runnables which are posted with delay. I suppose this is what causes the flicker. You could easily simply change the color at the place where you currently post your Runnables. Events ACTION_DOWN is when user presses button, and ACTION_UP when releases. So thats when you want to change colors. So instead of changeing back the background color in posted Runnable, do it when ACTION_UP of your button arrives (your have code for it in RepeatListener).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the class of the RepeatListener I don't know which custom made rectangle view is currently running. Not only do I have to know which of the rectangles is curring, but in my real app (instead of this example) there are many custom made rectangle views at the same time on the screen and only for some of them that fulfil a special condition, the background color should be changed. So either I don't understand your suggested approach, or it is simply not applicable to my question.

Comment: Iam afraid your problem require debugging of your real code. Often simplification might help find out problem, like my suggestion to remove posted runnables. This might show that problem might be in views animation, have you checked it? Here is related so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387711/android-animation-flicker

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually the animation itself works fine and there is no flickering. The flickering just comes when I want to change the color as long as the button is pressed. If I just want to change the color once (in a while) there is also no flickering. So I'd assume that there is no issue with the flickering. I still don't understand your suggested approach. How can I change something in the RepeatListener?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: No, sorry - nothing new comes to mind

Comment: Thanks marcinj. I could solve the problem by using your approach. It was not easy and I have to use a static variable and static method in the RepeatListener class to pass the the view that should be changed, but by doing this, I could solve the problem.